# Multiplying rasters by rasters within PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster, map-algebra

I have a situation where I have to multiply sets of rasters by each other.
Currently I have subfolders of rasters on my machine and am looping through them and multiplying them with rasterio.

Is there a way to multiply rasters by each other within PostGIS?

Raterio converts rasters into numpy matrix so multiplication is possible but can PostGIS's representation of a raster be multiplied by another PostGIS raster representation?

Is `ST_MapAlgebra` the way to do this?

And would anyone have a simple example of such a process?

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(a.rast, b.rast, '[rast1] * [rast2]') rast
FROM rasttablea rasttableb b;
```

This works fine if your rasters are not tiled. If they are tiled it's a bit more complicated...

Comment: Thank you. Ill give this a go.